# Recursive BST find element doesn't work well

Tags: c

this is my function to search in the BST:

```
BST* BSTFindElement(BST const *pTree, float find_value)
{
    if(pTree)
    {
        if(find_value > pTree->value)
            BSTFindElement(pTree->right, find_value);
        else if(find_value < pTree->value)
            BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value);
        return (BST*)pTree;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the float number is NOT in the tree,
in any way it returns (BST*)pTree.
I debugged and i noticed it does work well, if for example the root is '3.6' and i have searched for 5 it goes to the pTree->right and searching it, then when it skips
**if(pTree)** it returns the 0 but for some reason goes back to the top and returns (BST*)pTree again... i can't solve the problem myself, can anyone help me with it? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looking for 3.6 and the ptree->value is 5, so you go here :

```
else if(find_value < pTree->value)
        BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value);
```

then ptree is null so you return 0, you get back to previous stack frame, i mean exactly after the BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value); and the next statement is

```
return (BST*)pTree;
```

and this is what happens, you return ptree, destroying previously returned 0. If you rewrite it as :

```
else if(find_value < pTree->value)
        BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value);
else    
        return (BST*)pTree;
```

this still should not solve all the problem. I guess this will work

```
     if(find_value > pTree->value)
              **return** BSTFindElement(pTree->right, find_value);
    else if(find_value < pTree->value)
             **return** BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value);
    **else**
        return (BST*)pTree;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when the find value is different that the pTree value, then you always return the input pTree.
Have you tried changing your code to:

```
BST* BSTFindElement(BST const *pTree, float find_value){
if(pTree){
    if(find_value > pTree->value){
        return BSTFindElement(pTree->right, find_value);
    }
    else if(find_value < pTree->value){
        return BSTFindElement(pTree->left, find_value);
    }
    return (BST*)pTree;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```